# How would I construct a really simple java maths expression to be used with KNIME

Tags: java, knime

Im currently using a program called KNIME, which is used for analysing data. For some of my data, I want each row in a column to be averaged with the value in the previous row. The 'java snippet' option requires a 'global value declaration' and a 'method body'. The column name is 'new acc'. 
I understand to use this program more efficiently I'll probably need to learn simple java (and its on my to do), but just for this evening I would like a quick check on some of the data used. 
Any help is really appreciated - ive attached an image of the layout. [image]
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't required to use the Java Snippet, I'd recommend the [Math Formula](http://www.knime.org/files/nodedetails/_misc_Math_Formula.html) node.

Comment: the link provided is dead

Answer (score 1):

There's a Moving Average Node which might be suitable for the task.

Answer (score 0):

What about putting

```
double acc = Double.NaN;
```

to the global area, and something like this to the method body:

```
if (Double.isNaN(acc)) {
    acc = $z$;
    return $z$;
} else {
    double avg = (acc + $z$) / 2;
    acc = $z$;
    return avg;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a partial answer to the one from Sylvansight, it should be noted that the **Java Snippet** node is executed on a per row basis, so it's not even possible to use the **Java Snippet** node to access the values in the previous or subsequent rows.

Comment: You can store previous rows or aggregations in variables declared in the 'Global variables declaration' part of the snippet.  However, using the groupby node with no grouping columns, and aggregating the column you wish to average with the 'average' aggregator is probably the simplest way

Answer (score 0):

**Math formula node** fits better your problem, but if you want to use **java snippet node (simple) ** just put the formula in the return (using normal java sintax). `return 1+9;`